# Issue implementing a recursive shuffle array method in nlog(n) time

Tags: java, recursion, complexity-theory

I'm trying to implement a recursive shuffle method that will take nlog(n) time but am having major difficulty, given I am restricted to a single parameter and can't include the size of n in my params when calling the recursive method. I looked at the structure of a similar shuffling problem with different parameters and got the idea for how to structure the shuffling using Random, but I've spent way too much time trying to figure out how to implement this.

If I could implement the method taking two parameters, a and n, I don't feel like I would be having so much trouble. My question is, should I have n be a global variable for the purpose of decrementing it? How would I go about either decrementing n for the purpose of managing the recursion, or modify a somehow to eventually end the recursion?

*Also, would declaring the objects in the indices like this cause a referential issue? If so, how would I fix this? I tried clone and couldn't get it to function within the requirements of the problem.

```
    public static void shuffle(Object[] a) {
        int n = a.length;
        if (n == 0) {
            return;
         }
         int d = (int) (Math.random() * (n-1));  //random index
         Object c = a[n - 1];  //value at n-1
         a[n-1]= a[d]; //a[n-1] index = val at rand index
         a[d] =  c;         //val at rand index set to val at n-1
         shuffle(a);
        
        
        
        shuffle(a);
    }
```

***What I've started to implement which looks a lot more like it would work in nlogn time complexity, but not sure if it's right or how it would need to be finished...

```
public static void shuffle(Object[] a){
   if(a.length == 1) return;  //return if length = 1: base case 

    Object[] b = new Object[a.length/2]();
    Random rand = new Random(0,a.length); //random index to swap


   for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
       b[i] = a[rand];                 //how do I make sure no index of a is 
                    //repeated? 
  }

   shuffle(b); //recursively call shuffle on b, dividing size by 2

   for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
       a[i] = b[i];  //copy values from b to a (I guess you could use arraycopy)
   }

   }
```

Comment: If this was python, it'd make sense to restrict you to just passing the arrays. But in java you're going to face having to remake the sub-arrays without a way to pass around information about what you're supposed to look at. Perhaps you're allowed to use a private helper method `private static void shuffle(Object[] a, int n) { ... }` (in addition to the other method)

Comment: I've started trying to rebuild the method and this is what I've gotten so far:
```
public static void shuffle(Object[] a){
if(a.length == 1) return;  //return if length = 1: base case 

Object[] b = new Object[a.length/2]();
Random rand = new Random(0,a.length); //random index to swap


for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    b[i] = a[rand];                 //how do I make sure no index of a is 
        //repeated? 
}

shuffle(b); //recursively call shuffle on b, dividing size by 2

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
a[i] = b[i]; }
```

Comment: Ouch, that isn't going to format. Let me see if I can update the question to add what I've tried since then.

Comment: Do you want a O(n) - see `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)` - which runs in linear time?

Comment: Not trying to be obnoxious, but why?  [Shuffling can easily be done in O(n) time and O(1)  extra storage using iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).  It does not lend itself to divide and conquer strategies, because at each stage any of the remaining unshuffled items should be equally likely to end up in the location being considered, but each array location should only be considered once.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment and you absolutely have to use recursion, is it legal for you to write the recursive portion in a private "helper" method which allows you to pass indexing arguments rather than copying subsets of the array?

Comment: I'm not willingly writing this recursively by any means, it is most definitely part of an algorithm analysis class.

Answer (score 0):

> If I could implement the method taking two parameters, a and n, I don't feel like I would be having so much trouble. My question is, should I have n be a global variable for the purpose of decrementing it?

It does not have to be a global variable.  You can create a class inside your method as follows.   This should support any requirement that the implementation must be kept inside the publicly available method.  Of course, you'll need to decide if this is in accordance with any other restrictions not mentioned in your question.  I leave the actual algorithm up to you.  But the array can be shuffled in-place in O(n).

```
public static void shuffle(Object[] a) {
    class Shuffle {
        private void recShuffle(Object[] ob, int n) {
            // your shuffle algorithm here
        }
    }
    Shuffle s = new Shuffle();
    int n = ... // up to you
    s.recShuffle(a, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out a way to solve it this morning by implementing a helper method and moving most of my code there in case anyone ever comes across a problem like this:

```
    //calls helper shuffle method
     public static void shuffle(Object[] a) {
        int n = a.length;
         helperShuffle(a, n);
        
    }
    
    public static Object[] helperShuffle(Object[] a, int n) {
        if (n <= 1) 
            return a; //base case: size of array is 1 
        
        Random rand = new Random(); //declare new random
        int d = (rand.nextInt(n));  //random index < n 
        Object c = a[n - 1];  //value at n-1
        a[n-1]= a[d]; //a[n-1] index = val at rand index
        a[d] =  c;         //val at rand index set to val at n-1
        
        return helperShuffle(a,n-1); 
    }
```

Comment: Never ever ever instantiate new `Random` objects inside a method that will be called repeatedly!  You should create a single static instance in your main method.  What you're doing has a high likelihood of causing problems with correlated seeding, resulting in distinctly non-random results.  Also, it's far more costly to do it the way you currently are.  An analogy I like to give my students is that you should only dig one well and then draw water (random numbers) from it as needed.  You shouldn't dig a new well every time you want a drink of water.

Comment: This was the only way I was able to implement it within the given time frame, but still will end up losing points because it should have been implemented in O(nlogn) time (This one is O(n)). I had reached a point that if I continued I was going to neglect the rest of my workload implementing it and had to take the loss on it, unfortunately

Comment: The method does, however, provide distinctly random results. I ran it about 50 times to see that it was returning no duplicate entries and distinct shuffles each time.

Comment: You can't tell such things by eye.  Java uses a linear congruential generator, and that has the well-known result that generating new instances sequentially in time yields results which are collinear/correlated.  The solution is simple and shouldn't have taken you more than a couple of minutes -- declare `public static Random rand = new Random();` in the class or instantiate it in your `main`, not in your method. Then just use `rand.nextInt()` in your method.

Comment: `private static`, and ideally `final`. `public static` shouldn't be on any field outside of a constant imo. You might argue for something like `ThreadLocalRandom`/etc instead but `Random` itself is mutable.

Comment: @Rogue Agreed.  My focus was on getting the instantiation of `Random` out of the method.  I haven't been using Java for half a dozen years now, but still should have paid more attention.